# Translating "to tell" as a verb of understanding

Tags: traducción

How would the following sentences be translated?

> I can tell you are sad

(I understand that you are sad)

> Can you tell if the burner is hot?

(Do you know if the burner is hot?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here. You definitely can't just use `decir` in this situation, I don't think that would translate well.

As a quite literal translation, you could try

> *Puedo **ver** que estás triste.*

However a more "spanish" approach would probably be:

> *Se nota que estás triste*.

A different but potentially useful structure could be `Es + adjective`, e.g.

> Está claro / es obvio que estás triste.